# Logging out an user with Facebook SDK still remembers their details on the next login attempt

Tags: android, facebook

When the user logs in again a screen popups that says something like "You have previously logged in with Facebook, do you want to continue?"

Even if you press cancel there's no way to change to another user or log out properly. The only thing that seemed to work was setting this: facebookLoginButton.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_VIEW_ONLY);

That made the login window look very strange though.

Answer (score 0):

When you log out you must clear the Login Manager

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I initialize the SDK in the onCreate method and use the logout method, the issue is that the first method is deprecated and no longer necessary according to docs, and the second method is not needed since the user is technically already logged out, it just caches their details. I would use the second method if I had a custom button, for example. I just use the default one though.

Comment: I have a similar situation so I used `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` on my `LogOut()` and that's works for me.

Comment: I used an AccessTokenTracker and onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(), that's where I tried using LoginManager.getInstance().logOut(); before. It didn't work. I don't really have a LogOut() method that I call when the user presses the logout button. That is handled by the API, right?